# Problem with shiro 1.12.0 jar ,in forward .jsp pages in servlets request with out any sessions

Tags: servlets, shiro

Problem with shiro 1.12.0 jar ,in forward .jsp pages using servlets request , we will be forwording the .jsp in request ,using Requestdispatcher for the servlet GET request which usually reset password page which does not require login, but in response we are getting status code as 302 not modified , which occurs in our application were we recently updated the shiro-all jar version 1.12.0 from 1.7.0 am i missing any config in shiro ini were i have added the noSessionCreation property also and if i missing any  ?

with the shiro-all jar version 1.7.0 we are able forward the .jsp page but with the shiro-all 1.12.0 we are facing this problem.